# Figuring out which files where skipped during drag & drop

Tags: windows-7, logging, event-log

I just did a drag & drop on a windows system to move a large number of files. During this move there were a few errors involving corrupt files and other issues. Since I was doing this overnight I checked the "do this with all other files button". The question is: is there a log somewhere that would have recorded these errors and which files had what done to them?

Thanks

Comment: If you have moved the files won't any that failed to move still be where they were?

Answer (score 0):

You do this in command prompt to see the action as the files move.

Just do `copy [directory to copy; ex: C:\users\redraven\pictures] [location to copy to]` and this will list the files as they copy. It will also list the failed ones.

Comment: That helps for next time, but I'm trying to see if there is a log I can look at after the fact...

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows doesn't have a 'file operations' log.

If you think about it you can understand why, every file operation would mean changing this file...which would be a file operation...)

However surely as you were doing a move, the files are still in the original location?